# Mocking a Web Service and keep code coverage high

Tags: c#, mocking

Currently I have a Interface which looks like

```
interface IMyInterface
{
    public int GetValue(string name);

}
```

I am mocking such as:

```
class MyMockValid : IMyInterface
{
    public int GetValue(string name)
    {
        return 100;
    }

}

public testValidValue
{
    IMyInterface interface = new MyMockValid();
    Assert.IsEqual(100, interface.GetValue("Micheal");
}
```

Now the problem is when I try to code the actual getting from web service, I cannot get the code coverage to be 100% because the code never runs. Such as:

```
class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public int GetValue(string name)
    {
        //Do HTTPREQ using Name
        // Return the value from webservice
        return ValueFromService;
    }
}

class MyLibrary
{
    IMyInterface _interface;
    MyLibrary() { _interface = new MyClass(); }

    MyLibrary(IMyInterface Mockinterface)
    {
        _interface = Mockinterface;
    }

    public GetVal(string name)
    {
        return _interface.GetValue(name);
    }
}
```

How can I maintain a good code coverage when the GetValue from service never runs due to the mocking taking in effect?

Comment: Code coverage is not the end-all, be-all metric. You should use code coverage to determine if you have code that's not being tested *at all*. Having 100% code coverage doesn't mean that you don't have bugs. You should be testing actual use cases for your code, not chasing after an ultimately meaningless metric. That said, you could achieve higher code coverage in this case by having integration tests that validate that your code is calling the service correctly.

Comment: @DanielMann Does that mean it's OK if the `MyLibrary` class has a `50%` code coverage because the actual calling of the webservice `MyClass` is not run becuase of the mock? I know my mock is being tested thoroughly so that should be enough for me to go on.

Comment: I can't answer that question for you. Are *you* confident that your tests are correctly validating the intended function of the code? If so, proceed. If not, write more tests.